# Bulk operations with PostgreSQL database

Tags: c#, .net, database, postgresql, bulkupdate

I have almost 100k records in a dictionary. I need to update the single column value in a table based on other values, storing that mapping in a dictionary. I am using the below query to update the table, but it takes time.

Is there any way we can do a bulk update? I searched but could not find any proper solution to accomplish the bulk updates for PostgreSQL with c#?

I use PostgreSQL with c# and have a table with the below structure. I am using this namespace "System.Data.Common"

```
CREATE TABLE Days
(
    "Id" uuid NOT NULL,
)
```

And below is the code for the same.

```
 foreach (var dayKeyValuePair in dayIdByHashedkey)
 {
    migrationBuilder.Sql($"UPDATE \"Days\" SET \"Id\" = '{dayKeyValuePair.Value}' WHERE \"Id\" = '{dayKeyValuePair.Key}'");
 }
```

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: The details you are missing: The real table definition, all index definitions, the result of `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` for a slow statement. I personally think that that is not a reason to downvote, but to vote to close, but then votes are an expression of personal like or dislike more than anything else.

Comment: I have given the table definition, and it has other columns as well; I am updating the only one column that I mentioned in the question. I am using this one to migrate the table Id using c# and postgresql connector

Comment: But the speed of the update will also depend on the columns that you are *not* updating. In PostgreSQL, an update writes a new version *of the whole row*,

Comment: I did with splitting the rows into chunks of small size for process and this way works like charm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this problem by partitioning the rows into small parts of chunks and then processing those rows for the update below

```
var newDesignDays = dayKeyValuePair.Values.AsEnumerable();
foreach (var designDayChunk in newDesignDays.Chunk(1000))
{
     .....
     .....
     update statement
}
```